# WPF application crashes on start video capture

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, exception

i have developed one WPF camera video recording application. It works fine on my 64 bit machine as well as 32 bit machine . but it doesn't work on some machines gives  `"exception code c0000005"` how to handle that problem.